# Coxeter Systems and number of generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, lie-algebras

> Show that there exist Coxeter systems $(W, S)$ and $(W′
> , S′)$ with $|S|\not =|S′|$ such that $W$ is isomorphic to $W′$ as abstract groups.
>
> [Hint: Consider the dihedral group of order 12.]

Attempt: We can say $W$ is generated by $a,b$ such that $a^2=1, b^2=1,(ab)^6=1$.
Now if we pick for example $\rho=(ab)^3$ we have that $W$ is generated by $a,b,\rho$ such that $a^2=1,b^2=1,\rho^2=1,(ab)^6=1, (a\rho)^2=1, (b\rho)^2=1 $. But this is not a free group with Coxeter relations because $\rho=(ab)^3$, and if we remove this condition using a fresh new $\rho$ we obtain a bigger group than $W$. So I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\langle x,y,z \mid x^2,y^2,z^2,(xy)^3,(xz)^2,(yz)^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $12$.

Comment: @DerekHolt maybe set $x \to a, y\to bab, z \to ababab(=-1)$, they are "free" and they respect the relations so this is an explicit isomorpism. Correct?

Comment: Yes that works!